# How to see graphene-django DEBUG logs

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm having trouble viewing `DEBUG` level logs with Graphene and Django. I've set the following in `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
    },
}
```

However, when I try to look at the logs of my Django server all I see is:

```
 ❯❯❯ kubectl logs -f server-6b65f48895-bmp6w server
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, django_celery_results, server, sessions, social_django
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 08, 2018 - 23:59:00
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'backend.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 113
```

How can I view `DEBUG` level logs to figure out why my server is constantly serving 400s?

I have the Django `DEBUG` environment variable unset. I'm trying to debug a production issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was messed with the same question a while ago and came to the workaround solution:

```
from promise import is_thenable


class DebugMiddleware(object):
    def on_error(self, error):
        print(error)

    def resolve(self, next, root, info, **args):
        result = next(root, info, **args)
        if is_thenable(result):
            result.catch(self.on_error)

        return result
```

And tell `graphene` to use it as middleware:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    ...
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'path.to.containing.module.DebugMiddleware',
        ...
    ]
}
```

Here you get access to an error trowed on resolve.

Initial problem (no module logging) may be caused by disabled `graphql` logger, but my explorations in this direction didn't have any results :(

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you mind sharing how to wire this in properly too?

Comment: what's "is_thenable" ?

Comment: A utility function to determine if the specified object is a promise. Added missing import

Answer (score 0):

Based on @donnyy answer I came up with the following implementation

```
from promise import is_thenable
from functools import partial
import logging
import sys
import json
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)

class DebugMiddleware(object):
    def on_error(self, error ,info):
        log_request_body(info)

    def resolve(self, next, root, info, **args):

        result = next(root, info, **args)
        if is_thenable(result):
            result.catch(partial(self.on_error, info=info))
        return result


def log_request_body(info):
    body = info.context._body.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        json_body = json.loads(body)
        logging.error(' User: %s \n Action: %s \n Variables: %s \n Body: %s',
                      info.context.user,
                      json_body['operationName'],
                      json_body['variables'],
                      json_body['query'])
    except:
        logging.error(body)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick middleware I threw together to capture graphql query 400 errors.

In `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "path_to_file_below.GraphqlErrorLogMiddleware",
    ...
]

# Some basic logging from the Django Documentation
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {"console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler"}},
    "root": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "DEBUG"},
}
```

```
class GraphqlErrorLogMiddleware(object):
    """
    Logs errors for invalid graphql queries
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        try:
            if (
                400 >= response.status_code
                and response.status_code != 403
                and "graphql" in request.path.lower()
            ):
                response_json = json.loads(response.content)

                if "errors" in response_json:
                    log_response(
                        message=f"Graphql Error: {response_json['errors']}",
                        response=response,
                        level="error",
                    )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug(f"Error logging Graphql Error: {e}")

        return response
```